# eigenvalues of $I\otimes B\otimes C + A\otimes I \otimes C + A\otimes B \otimes I $

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, linear-algebra

Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be symmetric matrices.
What can we say about eigenvalues of $I\otimes B\otimes C + A\otimes I \otimes C + A\otimes B \otimes I $?

Comment: Why was this upvoted? It is an elementary question in linear algebra and not appropriate for the site. Voting to close. 

Comment: I confess, I am the guilty party.  Except when I forget, I almost always upvote a question that I answer.  If I felt like answering the question, then I figure that the question deserves my vote.

Comment: But note that someone else also upvoted the question.  Otherwise, I agree, it's on the easy side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The three terms commute, whether or not $A$, $B$, and $C$ are symmetric.  The eigenvalues are of the form $bc+ac+ab$, where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are eigenvalues of $A$, $B$, and $C$.  You just tensor eigenvectors together and you get the answer.